# How to catch the returned object from another process in C#

Tags: c#, process

I have a c# program that will call another c# program using Process.start() that I also have the source code.

How I can return a string for example from the second program that it can be read by the caller program.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to write it to the standard output (i.e. the console) of the "child" process. The "parent" process can then read the standard output (and error) of that process. See [`Process.StandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput).

Alternatively, you could use sockets, named pipes or something like that. That's certainly significantly harder, but would be appropriate if you wanted to make multiple requests/responses through the process.

Comment: @Mihai: I'm assuming the OP can adjust the child app accordingly.

Comment: Great! It worked thank you...
@mihai-caracostea no need to be a console.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an integer is trivial. Simply return an integer value from you main() function and it will be interpreted as the exit code which can be read by the calling process.

Other types involve cross-process communication and is, by no means, a walk in the park.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are good - you could potentially use a small file as a mean of communicating bigger strings.